# Can't add images in wordpress to my page - button isn't clickable

Tags: plugin-development

I"m try add  images as follow description but the button isn't clickable

[image]

Comment: What your JavaScript console say about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, Max pointed this out already - check what the console spits out when you click the button. On Chrome you can access the console via the Open Developer Tools (Win: F12, Ctrl + Shift + I | Mac: Cmd + Opt + I). The "Console" tab is what you are looking for. Have it open and then click the button again.